# How do I make related field that fetches all one2many values

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

Suppose I have the code like this:

```
'expenses'          : fields.related(
                    'property_expense_preset',
                    'expense_preset',
                    'expenses',
                    type="many2many",
                    relation="property.expense",
                    string="Routine Expenses",
                    store=False
                ),
```

Now `property_expense_preset` is a one2many field, which means there could be many of `property_expense_preset`s .But the code above only fetches the children of the first `property_expense_preset`. I want to show all of them instead. How do I do that?